# Función recibe un número y devuelva dos listas, una con cada factor común y otra con su exponente

Tags: python

Lo que no me sale, es imprimir la cantidad de veces que se repite los factores y devolverlos en otra lista.

---

```py
def FactorizarNumero(numero):
    factores = []
    exponetes = []
    
    if(type(numero) != int):
        return None
    if(numero == 1):
        return None
   
    for i in range(2, numero + 1):
        while numero % i == 0:
                factores.append(i)
                numero = numero / i  
    return (factores,exponetes)
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes! Podrías ir armando _la otra lista_ a medida que vas generando los factores, contar la ocurrencia de cada uno y entregar ese otro listado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta! A ver si me sale en el codigo. Esto lo haria por dentro del ciclo while?

Answer (score 1):

acá te propongo una solución, tené en cuenta que `set` que es una función propia de python toma una lista y te devuelve un set (una especie de conjunto donde los valores no pueden repetirse), entonces podés volver a transformarlo en lista (porque eso decís que necesitás). Después podés contar cuantas veces aparece cada elemento en la lista principal usando `.count(elemento)` esto lo hago en el código con un for comprehension (un for puesto en una sola línea para ahorrar espacio vertical en el código).

Por último si bien tu código base funciona, propongo una variación, porque así como lo escribiste va a tardar mucho, fijate que recorres todos los valores hasta numero por más que termines de encontrar los coeficientes. esto va a hacer que si trabajás con un número muy grande tardes mucho más de lo que deberías.

```
def FactorizarNumero(numero):
    factores = []
    #exponentes = []
    
    if(type(numero) != int):
        return None
    if(numero == 1):
        return None
   
    for i in range(2, numero + 1):
        while numero % i == 0:
                factores.append(i)
                numero = numero / i  
    
    fact_unic = list(set(factores))
    exponentes = [factores.count(i) for i in fact_unic]
    return (fact_unic,exponentes)


def FactorizarNumero2(numero):
    factores = []
    if(type(numero) !=int):
        return None
    if numero == 1:
        return None
    div=2
    while numero >1:
        while numero%div==0:
            factores.append(div)
            numero=numero/div
        div+=1
    
    fact_unic = list(set(factores))
    exponentes = [factores.count(i) for i in fact_unic]
    return (fact_unic,exponentes)


a = (2**8) * (3**4) * (5**5) #acá construyo el número para que el resultado sea
# ([2,3,5], [8,4,5])

from time import time

t1 = time()
print(FactorizarNumero(a))
t2 = time()
print(FactorizarNumero2(a))
t3 = time()

print("FactorizarNumero: ", t2-t1)
print("FactorizarNumero2: ", t3-t2)

#El resultado:
#-------------
#([2, 3, 5], [8, 4, 5])
#([2, 3, 5], [8, 4, 5])
# FactorizarNumero:  4.927767753601074
# FactorizarNumero2:  9.322166442871094e-05
```

Espero se entienda, cualquier cosa avisá

Answer (score 0):

```
def FactorizarNumero2(numero):
    factores = []
    if(type(numero) !=int):
        return None
    if numero == 1:
        return None
    div=2
    while numero >1:
        while numero%div==0:
            factores.append(div)
            numero=numero/div
        div+=1
    
    fact_unic = list(set(factores))
    exponentes = [factores.count(i) for i in fact_unic]
    return (fact_unic,exponentes)
a = 1428 #acá construyo el número para que el resultado sea
# ([17,2,3,7], [1,2,1,1])# pero lo esperado es 
#([2,3,7,17],[2,1,1,1]# como cambio de posición el numero 17, para quedar ordenado
```

Comment: Por favor, no incluyas preguntas en tu respuesta. Principalmente porque es muy improbable que así alguien la conteste. Mejor crea tu propia pregunta y referencia esta si lo crees necesario. Lee [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Hola Cesar, bienvenido, esta es la zona de respuestas, te sugiero que elimines tu comentario, a fin de evitar recibir votos negativos

si tienes alguna duda, crea tu propia pregunta, para recibir ayuda, antes 

mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.